# Does supporting Diana Allers mean that you can no longer kick her off the Normandy?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The first few times I've visited Diana Allers in her cabin, I've had the option to kick her off the Normandy:

Recently, she argued with a crew member about whether or not to run a story and I took her side.  Afterwards, I found that the dialogue option to kick her off the ship was no longer available.

**Does supporting Diana mean that she becomes a permanent part of the crew?**

Comment: Did you try talking to her twice in quick succession?

Comment: @Tristan - I didn't think to try that, no

Comment: I know there were a few instances for me where I would run up to her to talk to her and she would simply say "Shepard." If I hit talk again right after, it would bring up the option to kick her off the ship. Since I don't remember supporting her, though, I won't post this as an answer, as I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Tristan - I just tried it, you were right.  Post that as your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will eventually reach a point where, upon talking to Diana, she will simply say, "Shepard." As soon as that happens, choose to talk to her again.

You'll be met with two options upon doing so:

**That will be all.** or **Get off my ship.**

Simply choose the latter and Allers will leave. And take her horrible voice acting with her!

Comment: You just burst my Jessica Chobot bubble >.<....